# How to change a styled button background colour without having to create a drawable for each of them?

Tags: android

I need to apply a "double-layered" background to a button (or a view with an OnClickListener): the layer below is solid-coloured, the layer above is a frame.
Is there a way to change the colour on the go?
[image]

Comment: Did you look at `layer-list`? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

Comment: Yes, but I did not find how to change it programatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just try and have 2 views instead of one. You could have a `LinearLayout` with a `ImageView` inside it. The `LinearLayout` would have the colour you want and the `ImageView` would just be rendered on top of the `LinearLayout` background, unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, solved it by having the button on top of a solid-colour `View` aligned to each other inside a `RelativeLayout`